# Yarn build failing because of babel plugin "Error: Cannot find package '@babel/plugin-preset-plugin-proposal-class-properties'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, babeljs, yarnpkg

I'm working on a rails 7 app that uses yarn. I've been trying for several hours to debug an issue during the built process without luck.
When I call `yarn build`, the build fails with:

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ webpack --config config/webpack/webpack.config.js
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: Cannot find package '@babel/plugin-preset-plugin-proposal-class-properties' imported from [my project path]/babel-virtual-resolve-base.js
    at new NodeError ([my project path]/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/vendor/import-meta-resolve.js:203:5)

....

at loadPlugin ([my project path]/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:47:20) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v20.3.1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

The built previously has been failing repeatedly because of other packages that were missing and I resolved the issue buy adding them into the config but the '@babel/plugin-preset-plugin-proposal-class-properties' plugin doesn't seem to exist when I try to install it with npm or when I try to look it up on npmjs.com.

My babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  var validEnv = ['development', 'test', 'production']
  var currentEnv = api.env()
  var isDevelopmentEnv = api.env('development')
  var isProductionEnv = api.env('production')
  var isTestEnv = api.env('test')

  if (!validEnv.includes(currentEnv)) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please specify a valid `NODE_ENV` or ' +
        '`BABEL_ENV` environment variables. Valid values are "development", ' +
        '"test", and "production". Instead, received: ' +
        JSON.stringify(currentEnv) +
        '.'
    )
  }

  return {
    presets: [
      isTestEnv && [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          targets: {
            node: 'current'
          }
        }
      ],
      (isProductionEnv || isDevelopmentEnv) && [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          forceAllTransforms: true,
          useBuiltIns: 'entry',
          corejs: 3,
          modules: false,
          exclude: ['transform-typeof-symbol']
        }
      ]
    ].filter(Boolean),
    plugins: [
      'babel-plugin-macros',
      '@babel/preset-plugin-proposal-class-properties',
      '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
      isTestEnv && 'babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node',
      '@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring',
      [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        {
          loose: true
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
        {
          useBuiltIns: true
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods',
        {
          loose: true
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object',
        {
          loose: true
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
        {
          helpers: false
        }
      ],
      [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator',
        {
          async: false
        }
      ]
    ].filter(Boolean)
  }
}
```

and my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Project Name",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "=20"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10",
    "@gorails/ninja-keys": "^1.2.1",
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.2.2",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^7.2.0",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^7.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^7.0.0",
    "@rails/request.js": "^0.0.8",
    "@rails/ujs": "^7.0.0",
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.0",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
    "chokidar": "^3.5.2",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.8",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "debounced": "^0.0.5",
    "esbuild": "^0.18.0",
    "esbuild-rails": "^1.0.3",
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.10",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "jstz": "^2.1.1",
    "local-time": "^2.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.8",
    "postcss-import": "^15.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.66.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "stimulus_reflex": "^3.5.0-rc3",
    "stimulus-flatpickr": "^3.0.0-0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.0",
    "tailwindcss-stimulus-components": "^3.0.4",
    "tippy.js": "^6.3.5",
    "tom-select": "^2.2.2",
    "tributejs": "^5.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-remove-empty-scripts": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "tailwindcss --postcss --minify -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css",
    "build": "webpack --config config/webpack/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm working with babel for the first time, so it's possible that I'm doing plenty wrong. I'd appreciate a pointer if you know what's going wrong.